# ArcGIS Desktop can't return concurrent license

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager

We have one concurrent use ArcView license, managed by a license server box in the office. The server reports that one of our desktops has the license 'borrowed', but when looking at the Desktop Admin tool on that box, it doesn't show anything about having a license checked out. It seems the license is somewhere lost in the ether.

Is there a way, from the desktop side, to 'force return' or destroy the local license file? There appears to be no way for me to get the license returned from the desktop side. I've filed a report with Esri, but not holding out hope that my issue will be fixed ASAP.

Anyone here have experience with this problem? Would a reinstall of the desktop software help?

Comment: default borrowing is 30 days. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00030000000t000000.htm you need to return it then needs to be done on the server side and the desktop should return it if communication is good.

Comment: My problem right now is that the desktop machine in question doesn't show anything under the 'current borrowed licenses' menu in the Desktop Administrator. So I _can't_ return the borrowed license at all.

Comment: restarting the license server can sometimes help with these disagreements. After having a similar problem I made sure to always reduce the license borrowing time limit to 1 day so that things would always fix themselves soon enough

Comment: I've tried restarting the license server a number of times, but that doesn't seem to help. I still see zero licenses available on both sides. This is beyond frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reran the server-side authorization and it seemed to usurp the old license. But not sure this would work in all cases for all people.

Answer (score 1):

[This ArcGIS forum thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/57685-Return-Borrowed-License-From-Server-Side) suggests that simply changing the date on the server to fool it into thinking that the time was up might work.